# How to fix: 'TypeError: Cannot initialize connector undefined:' while use loopback-connector-firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, loopback

I tried several answers from stackoverflow but cannot solve the problem, I want to connect the firestore to loopback using this package: loopback-connector-firestore (https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-connector-firestore), after create the datasource using `lb datasource` command and start the system, error below will show out:

```
TypeError: Cannot initialize connector undefined: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

The loopback already connected to other datasource. How can I add firestore into it?

This is the `datasources.json` file:

```
{
  -----other db datasources here-----

  "Firestore": {
    "name": "Firestore",
    "projectId": "project id",
    "clientEmail":  "client email",
    "privateKey": "key here",
    "databaseName": "name here",
    "connector": "loopback-connector-firestore"
  }
}
```

In `server.js` file:

```
var ds = loopback.createDataSource({
    connector: require('loopback-connector-firestore'),
    provider: 'Firestore'
});

var storage = ds.createModel('storage');
app.model(storage);
```

The environment settings:

```
* Kubuntu 18.04
* nodejs v10.16
* npm v6.9
* loopback v3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for now the some of the connectors aren't supported by Loopback, and 'Loopback-firebase-connector' is one of them.
you may need to check the following:

Reference: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Community-connectors.html